# C++ SDK WFP callout functions

Tags: c++, sdk, callback

Nowadays I am doing some research on WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) functions. But after googling for last 5days I did not find a single example of WFP callout functions. Would anyone please share some codes on it ?

Thanks.

Comment: My suspicion would be that googling for WPF functions would be more fruitful. WFP doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: @MSalters: Sorry. WFP stands for Windows Filtering Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample is [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/onoj/windows-filtering-platform-sample?wa=wsignin1.0).  The download link is dead, it got [moved here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/1/2/f12dbbb5-d164-4e7c-b42d-aaca3efb85dc/WFPSample.EXE).

Comment: Hmm, I'll give you 10 minutes to figure out what happens when you run it.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know its a package exe.

Answer (score 0):

That link seems broken. I would suggest to check always the samples included in the DDK, they are great:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568374(v=vs.85).aspx